# Facing strange issue in drupal 6 images

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I had insert an image in the right sidebar and it is working fine in the front page but in other pages (there is a page called city in my site), images are not getting displayed including sidebar image. Same path and everything is same, still images are not getting displayed where in same images are displayed in front/home page.
my image path is sites/default/files/images and my site is
http://netelityeasylife.com/drupal

Please someone help me in this.Suggest me where i should make changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the main page, the URL to `adv1.gif` resolves as

```
http://netelityeasylife.com/drupal/sites/default/files/images/adv1.gif
```

On the cities page, it is

```
http://netelityeasylife.com/drupal/node/sites/default/files/images/adv1.gif
                                   ^^^^
```

The image URL is encoded in the HTML as `sites/default/files/images/adv1.gif`. Given the actual URL of the page you are looking at, this won't resolve correctly.

One way of getting around this problem is to hard-code the image URL in your node, or to provide a URL which would resolve correctly given the base of your public HTML folder, such as

```
/sites/your_site/image_folder/image_filename
```

Comment: "hard-code the image URL in your node" i didnt get this. Sorry. and i have installed drupal in netelityeasylife.com, so here /sites/your_site/image_folder/image_filename, within sites directory, do you suggest me to create another folder by my sitename?
Please help me out :(

Comment: Hi, I have found the solution to this problem. Just need to give the complete path!!!

Comment: One more problem i am facing, i have created drop dowm i mean secondary menu, but on mouse over its not showing. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have drupal installed in directory i.e drupal.

Open settings.php and set

```
$base_path = 'http://netelityeasylife.com/drupal';
```

Comment: i have set the base path , still the problem not resolved :(. Any other way to get rid of this wired problem .. please suggest